# getting `Failed to transform exoplayer-hls-2.17.1.aar` error after install audio_waveforms package

Tags: flutter, audiowaveform

I add audio_waveforms package on my flutter app but I can't build or run the project. it shows me blow error.

My System Info:
Linux Ubuntu: 22.04.3
flutter: 3.10.6
Dart: 3.0.6

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':audio_waveforms_fix:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':audio_waveforms_fix:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform exoplayer-hls-2.17.1.aar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.17.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-symbol-with-package-name, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Could not find exoplayer-hls-2.17.1.aar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.17.1).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/exoplayer/exoplayer-hls/2.17.1/exoplayer-hls-2.17.1.aar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

[image]

I try several solution but it doesn't work. and also I asked chat GPT and bard but thay couldn't help me. if anyone face with this issue before please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution. so If you need to use the audio_waveforms flutter package just install `ffmpeg` application on your linux.

How install ffmpeg?

1- `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`

2- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media`

3- `sudo apt-get update`

4- `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

5- sudo apt-get install ffmpeg

bingoo now I can use `audio_waveforms` package in my project.

[How to Install FFmpeg on Linux](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ffmpeg#Installing_FFmpeg_on_Ubuntu)